# How to add specific files to project from github through cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

There is this library on github: https://github.com/ConventionalC/ConventionalC
To Install this entire library, I have to add this to the Podfile: `pod "ConventionalC/ios", "~> 0.11"`
But I don't need the entire library. I just need two files from it: `CALayer+XibConfiguration.h & CALayer+XibConfiguration.m` which are placed in the directory ios.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install just that with `CocoaPods`.
You can do that **just if that pods is organized also for install submodules**. This is not the case.

Moreover, if you need just those class (20 lines in total maybe), there is no really reason to use `CocoaPods`. Rather simply **download those 2 file and drag them in your project**.